# Require not loading jquery file upload plugins

Tags: jquery, requirejs, jquery-file-upload

I've been searching for an answer in the require docs and thorough SO, but I cannot manage to solve this issue: require doesn't download the jquery plugins needed for jquery file upload.

I use backbone in the client and jade in the server.

In the jade layout template I have this:

```
script(data-main='js/boot.js', type='text/javascript',src='js/libs/require.js')
```

In boot.js I have this:

```
require.config({

  paths: {
    jquery: '/js/libs/jquery',
    Underscore: '/js/libs/underscore',
    Backbone: '/js/libs/backbone',
    models: 'models',
    collections: 'collections',
    text: '/js/libs/text',
    templates: '../templates',
    jqueryw: '/js/libs/jquery.ui.widget',
    jqfuit: '/js/libs/jquery.iframe-transport',
    jqfu: '/js/libs/jquery.fileupload',
    SubNetView: '/js/SubNetView',
    subNet: '/js/SubNet'
  },

  shim: {
    'jqueryw': ['jquery'],
    'jqfuit': ['jquery'],
    'jqfu': ['jquery','jqueryw'],
    'Backbone': ['Underscore', 'jquery'],
    'subNet': ['Backbone']
  }
});

require(['subNet'], function(subNet) {
  subNet.initialize();
});
```

All referenced files are downloaded, but

```
jqueryw: '/js/libs/jquery.ui.widget',
jqfuit: '/js/libs/jquery.iframe-transport',
jqfu: '/js/libs/jquery.fileupload',
```

Any help will be much appreciated.